# How to use help() in Python?

Tags: python, prompt

I have a problem with the function help() in python.
Using the prompt I input:

```
>>> help(str.strip)
```

And returns:

`'more' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file.`

I use python 3.9.2 on Windows

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more code please?

Comment: try this help ```("str.strip")``` pass this as string

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm guessing that Python is attempting to find a pager, tries to resort to `less` and/or `more` and can't find either

Comment: On what environment are you running Python (Windows/Mac/Linux(which?))?

Comment: I use vs code on windows

Comment: Using `help("str.strip")` I have the same problem